# how to append certain row of different matrices to construct a new dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a list of 10 matrices called mat.list, each is a 3 by 20 matrix, mat1 to mat10.
I want to make a dataframe whose rows are the first row of each matrix. hence a 10 by 20 dataframe.

```
for(i in 1:10){
  my.df <- rbind(my.df , mat.list[[i]][i,])
}
```

this is not doing what I want. it appends many more rows. how can I do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the `list` with `lapply`, extract the first row and `rbind` the `list` elements

```
my.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(mat.list, function(x) x[1, , drop = FALSE]))
```

Or use `head`

```
my.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(mat.list, head, 1))
```

Comment: the head trick is very interesting. I tried it for tail too. is there anything like this for a middle row ( when there are three rows in total? )

Comment: @Mathica middle implies, it can be different with even/odd number of rows

Comment: @Mathica,  May be you can do `function(x) x[ceiling(nrow(x)/2), , drop = FALSE]))` or `floor` (depending on how you wanted